# How Native method work inside source code without loading native library inside class?

Tags: java

I was going through source code of FileInputStream, i saw many native method signature, but could not find "System.Load" anywhere inside source code. So my question is how those native method works without loading native library? I tried hard but could not find the right answer

Comment: Well, the JVM itself is a native application so the basic native code can be assumed to be present already. You'd need to load any _additional_ native libs but not the standard parts of the JVM.

Comment: can you elaborate your answer with exact instance? Or any documentation? Or any documented specification?

Comment: Well, I'm not aware of any such documentation or specification (exception what bracco23 posted already) but that doesn't mean there isn't any. On the other hand it might be up to the JVM implementation as well. Is there any specific reason you want/need to know where the native libs are loaded?

Answer (score -1):

According to the [Java Virtual Machine Specs 1.12](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se12/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.12) a compliant virtual machine must

> provide sufficient support for the implementation of the class libraries of the Java SE Platform.

EDIT:

In the specs nothing says that implementation must be done in a separate library. The JVM is allowed to not put the native implementation in a separate library but to have them as part of the JVM code itself. In that case what library should the code load?

I think the assumption here is that the JVM is in charge of having the method properly loaded before it is executed, the library can just invoke it without having to care about loading libraries and such.

In contrast, the native implementation of custom defined methods is in charge of the developer, so he/she must load the native library before invoking the method.

Comment: It is clear from your reference that JVM must provide those support library, but should not FileInputStream Load that? Does loading is implicit? where this has been  specified?

Comment: @Rafa why should `FileInputStream` load the library? Why should the library be specific to that class at all? The exact layout of the native code might depend on the exact JVM version being used.

Comment: @thomos "why should load the library?"  Well this how we can use native method of that class isn't it ? Native method support  file are supposed to load inside static block while class itself is loading.  We always do this using System.Load while implementing our own native method.